# Macbook Pro won't shut down

Tags: macos, shutdown

I recently bought the 13"Macbook Pro retina (mid 2014). When I try to shut the laptop down, it doesn't work. I tried by manually closing all open applications but nothing happens when I press `Apple Menu > Shutdown`. I also tried by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>off</kbd> but same results.

Comment: did you also try Apple Menu > Shutdown? What happens?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean by 'pressing shutdown', Restart isn't working either. Sleep is working though.

Comment: if you wait, eventually [maybe 2 mins] it ought to tell you what is preventing it… or check Cmd/Opt/Esc & see if something is showing as Not Responding. BTW, just holding the Power button will force shutdown, but that's a last resort.

Comment: Maybe try shutting down from the command line? Open the application `Terminal` and type `sudo shutdown -h now`. Enter your password when prompted and press enter. What happens if you try that?

Comment: After the force restart everything looks to be working as normal. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which app is preventing the shutdown use

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>

Try to force quit it from that screen.

If all fails hold the Power button for 10 seconds.

That is the most crude way to shut down and as last option.

Answer (score -2):

This works if all else fails:

```
sudo shutdown
```

Comment: At least on my Mac, `shutdown` requires some options...